# How do I count how many reads went to my MySQL slave db?

Tags: mysql, select, replication, master-slave, slave

We are using MySQL 5.5.37, Java 6, and JBoss 7.1.3.AS.  We have a MySQL master and a read-replica.  Our JDBC connection string is as follows:

```
jdbc:mysql:replication://master:3306,slave:3306/dbid?failOverReadOnly=true
```

My quesiton is, in MySQL, how do I count how many read (SELECT) operations have been directed to my slave database and how many are still being handled by the master?